# find and replace at half index instance

Tags: java, regex

My text and regex looks like this

```
String text = "dummy:10.45someObjectdummy:10.67somethingdummy:10.78somethingdummy:10.98djd";
String regex = "dummy:(\\d+\\.\\d+)";
```

In this I get four matches for the regex. There will always be event number of matches. I want to compare sum of first half and second half. If sum of first half is lesser than second half , then add `1.00` in first half otherwise add `1.00` in second half.

In this case sum of first half is 10.45 + 10.67.
sum of second half is 10.78 + 10.98.

So we will add 1.00 in 10.67 and our final string would be

```
String text = "dummy:10.45someObjectdummy:11.67somethingdummy:10.78somethingdummy:10.98djd";
```

Here is what I have tried.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class MatcherTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        String text = "dummy:10.45someObjectdummy:10.67somethingdummy:10.78somethingdummy:10.98djd";
        String regex = "dummy:(\\d+\\.\\d+)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);
        List<Double> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(1));
            itemList.add(Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1)));
        }


    }
}
```

Now I have the itemList, I can check which part is greater, based on that how to replace the 2nd or 4th item. ? 
Please note that there can be total 6, 8 item also. So we would need to replace accordingly.

Comment: what if you have 6 element so you have to check 3 first with the 3 last or 2 by 2?

Comment: 3 first and 3 last and have to update 3rd or 6th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to know how many matches there are in the string, you need to 1) get all the matches, and 2) perform all necessary manipulations, and 3) replace the right match with the updated value.

Here is a [quick Java demo](http://ideone.com/cEiZBt) that you may further enhance:

```
String s = "dummy:10.45someObjectdummy:10.67somethingdummy:10.78somethingdummy:10.98djd";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("dummy:(\\d+\\.\\d+)").matcher(s);
List<Double> vals = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()){
    vals.add(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)));  // Collecting matches
} 
int val_id = vals.size() / 2 - 1;           // Finding out the index of the value to update
Double updated_val = vals.get(val_id);      // Getting the value
// System.out.println("We need to update " + updated_val); // => We need to update 10.67
updated_val = updated_val + 1;             // Incrementing the value
String replace_pattern = "(dummy:(?:\\d+\\.\\d.*?dummy:){" + (val_id) + "})\\d+\\.\\d+";
// System.out.println("New pattern: " + replace_pattern); // => New pattern: (dummy:(?:\d+\.\d.*?dummy:){1})\d+\.\d+
String result = s.replaceFirst(replace_pattern, "$1" + updated_val); // Replacing
System.out.println(result);
// => dummy:10.45someObjectdummy:11.67somethingdummy:10.78somethingdummy:10.98djd
```

The pattern is `(dummy:(?:\d+\.\d.*?dummy:){1})\d+\.\d+` (where `1` is dynamic):

- `(dummy:(?:\d+\.\d.*?dummy:){1})` - Group 1 matching

  - `dummy:` -  a `dummy:` string
  - `(?:\d+\.\d.*?dummy:){1}` -  *n* (here, 1) occurrences of:

    - `\d+\.\d` - 1+ digits, `.` and a digit
    - `.*?` -  any 0+ chars other than newline (add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern if the string contains newlines) as few as possible
    - `dummy:` -  a `dummy:` string
- `\d+\.\d+` - 1+ digits, `.` and again 1+ digits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to replace the floats inside, you can use the followin:

```
String regex =  "dummy:[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+"
```

You can try it here:

http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRj6kok8DA/index.html